# What does the symbol $ \#$ represent in mathematics?

Tags: notation, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

What does the symbol $ \#$ represent in mathematics?

For example,

In J. Neukirch's algebraic number theory book (page $171$), it has been mentioned that-

> the number $\# W_v$ of extensions equals the index $(G:G_w)$.

where $W_v$ is the set of extensions of valuations $v$ and $G_w$ is the decomposition group of automorphism.

What does the symbol $\#$ represent here?

Does this mean dimension or number?

Comment: It is the symbol for cardinality.

Comment: @KaboMurphy, thank you

Comment: I found this helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#In_mathematics

Comment: @C.Melton, thanks

Comment: There is similar (but different) symbol $\sharp$ also used in mathematics,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3099693/442